# Accessing from modules a filehandle defined in main program

Tags: perl, module, filehandle

I have following query in Perl regarding the accessing of file handlers.

Consider the following code snippet which describes the exact scenario.

#### Main.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
use strict 'refs';

use File::Basename;
use Fcntl ':flock';

use feature qw/say switch/;

use File::Spec::Functions;
use File::Find;

require( "/home/rxa3kor/Mastering_Perl/sample.pm" );

our $LOGFILE = "sample";
open( LOGFILE, ">$LOGFILE" ) or die "__ERROR: can't open file\n'", $LOGFILE, "'!\n";
flock( LOGFILE, LOCK_EX );
print LOGFILE ( "Tool Start\n" );

&sample::func();

flock( LOGFILE, LOCK_UN );
close( LOGFILE );
```

#### sample.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
package sample;

sub func() {
    print $main::LOGFILE ( "Printing in subroutine\n" );
}
```

when I execute the above said code snippet I am getting the following error.

> print() on unopened filehandle Mastering at /home/rxa3kor/Mastering_Perl/sample.pm line 6.

Th error is because the filehandle `LOGFILE` is not visible under `sample.pm` module.

How this concept can be implemented?

I want to open a file in `Main.pl` and I need this file handle to be accessible in different Perl modules.

Comment: I don't think this is the code you are using. This code doesn't compile. You are missing a semicolon at the end of the `use File::Find` line. And once I fix that, I get another problem as you are not loading `sample.pm` in your main program. Please don't waste our time by posting sample code where we have to fix simple errors like that.

Comment: Two more errors. `sample.pm` does not return a true value. And the filename is different between this sample code and the error message that you quote.

Comment: Basically i wanted to know whether we can open a file under main.pl and i need this file handle to be accessible in different Perl modules.

Comment: Find the updated code where we get the exact error message .

Comment: sample.pm contains some functionalities which are required by the main package. During the course of execution of sample.pm i need all the major functionalities to be written to the log file. Basically i wanted to find a method how we can have single log file which contains the output starting from main to all the other different sub routines.

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem that you are asking about, but what do you think will happen when you open your logfile in `'>'` mode, and then discover you're unable to obtain an exclusive lock because someone else has it locked?

Comment: Hint: Clobber-output mode will clobber the output file before you've obtained a lock. This means if someone else already had the file opened with a lock, you just clobbered them.

Comment: Basically is there a way to access a file handle which is defined in main.pl to be accessed in other Perl modules ?

Comment: To solve the problem you are asking about: Try this (untested): `*sample::LOGFILE = *main::LOGFILE; print LOGFILE "boo\n";`  You're dealing with typeglob filehandles here, so you have the semantics of typeglobs available to you.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't give the error message that you claim it gives.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you're seeing this error is that `$main::LOGFILE` refers to the scalar variable `$LOGFILE` which contains the filename, `sample`. The filehandle, `LOGFILE`, is a completely different variable. And here we see the dangers of having two variables of different types (scalar vs filehandle) with the same name.

Bareword filehandles (the ones in capital letters with no sigil attached, the type you are using) are slightly strange variables. They don't need a sigil, so you shouldn't use one. So the simplest fix is to just remove the `$`.

```
sub func()
{
  print main::LOGFILE ("Printing in subroutine\n");
}
```

But using global variables like this is a terrible idea. It will quickly lead to your code turning into an unmaintainable mess.

Far better to use a *lexical* filehandle and to pass that into your subroutine.

```
our $LOGFILE="sample";
open( my $log_fh, ">$LOGFILE" ) or die "__ERROR: can't open file\n'",$LOGFILE,"'!\n";
flock( $log_fh, LOCK_EX );
print $log_fh ("Tool Start\n");
&sample::func($log_fh);
flock( $log_fh, LOCK_UN );
close( $log_fh );
```

And in `sample.pm`:

```
sub func
{
  my ($fh) = @_;
  print $fh ("Printing in subroutine\n");
}
```

Note that as I'm now passing a parameter to `func()`. I've removed the prototype saying that it takes no parameters (although the fact that you were calling it with `&` turns off parameter checking!)

A few other points.

- You don't need both `-w` and `use warnings`. Remove the `-w`.
- You don't need both `use strict` and `use strict 'refs'`. Remove the latter.
- Modules with all lower-case names are reserved for special Perl features called **pragmas**. Don't name your modules like that.
- There's no need for `$LOGFILE` to be a package variable (defined with `our`). Just make it a lexical (defined with `my`).
- There is no reason to call subroutines with `&` (and, in fact, it has a couple of downsides that will confuse you).
- Don't define subroutines with prototypes unless you know what they are for.
- No need for a shebang line in modules.
- Use `strict` and `warnings` in modules.

I'd write your code like this:

```
# main.pl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Basename; # Not used. Remove?
use Fcntl ':flock'; # Not used. Remove?
use feature qw/say switch/;
use File::Spec::Functions; # Not used. Remove?
use File::Find; # Not used. Remove?
use Sample;

my $LOGFILE = 'sample';
# Lexical filehandle. Three-arg version of open()
open( my $log_fh, '>', $LOGFILE )
  or die "__ERROR: can't open file\n'$LOGFILE'!\n";
flock( $log_fh, LOCK_EX );

print $log_fh ("Tool Start\n");
Sample::func($log_fh);

flock( $log_fh, LOCK_UN );
close( $log_fh );
```

And...

```
package Sample;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub func {
  my ($fh) = @_;
  print $fh ("Printing in subroutine\n");
}

1;
```

Comment: Is there any method where we can avoid passing the file handler to a subroutine ? I need to directly access the file handler in the perl module which is present in main,pl. Reason for this requirement is because i may have different Perl modules and different subroutines inside each modules, every time i need to pass the file handlers to each of these subroutines in Perl module. Another difficulty will be always subroutine need not be called from main.pl file, subroutine defined in a *.pm file may call other subroutine which is defined in another *.pm module.

Comment: @RotchMiller: My answer already tells you how to do that. But I think it's a very bad idea.

Comment: Main underlying problem is the way how the file handler's can be made visible in the subroutine of different Perl modules. Like how we have to export a scalar variables from one *.pm module to any perl modules using the EXPORTER, similar concept for file handlers would be good.

Comment: @RotchMiller: Exporter works fine for filehandles. Obviously not if they're lexical variables. But for package variables and bareword filehandles, there's no problem.

Comment: @RotchMiller The traditional way to make a variable visible within subroutines in many different modules is to pass it in as a parameter. But if you want to ignore seventy years of good software engineering practice - feel free :-)

Comment: @DaveCross : While this wasn't part of his question, the examples provided here seem to all still allow the file-locking race condition of opening a file in output/create/truncate mode, and *then* asking for an exclusive lock. If another process was holding a lock, this truncation would wreak havoc.

Comment: @DavidO: Feel free to post an answer that fixes that :-)

Answer (score 2):

You've got an extremely detailed analysis [from Dave Cross](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235447/4653379).

Here I'd like to offer a way to cleanly provide a log file for all modules to write to.

Introduce a module that performs the writes to a log file in a sub; load it by all modules that need that. In that sub open the log file to append, using [state](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) filehandle which thus [stays open](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Persistent-Private-Variables) across the calls. Then the modules write by invoking this sub, and this can be initiated by a call from `main`.

The logger module

```
package LogAll;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say state);
use Carp qw(croak);    
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(write_log);

sub write_log {
    state $fh = do {               # initialize; stays open across calls
        my $log = 'LOG_FILE.txt';
        open my $afh, '>>', $log or croak "Can't open $log: $!";
        $afh;
    };  
    say $fh $_ for @_;
}
1;
```

Two other modules, that need to log, are virtually the same for this example; here is one

```
package Mod1;

use warnings;
use strict;

use Exporter qw(import);    
use LogAll qw(write_log);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(f1);

sub f1 {
    write_log(__PACKAGE__ . ": @_");
}
1;
```

The main

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use LogAll qw(write_log);    
use Mod1 qw(f1);
use Mod2 qw(f2);

write_log('START');

f1("hi from " . __PACKAGE__);
f2("another " . __PACKAGE__);
```

A run results in the file `LOG_FILE.txt`

```
START
Mod1: hi from main
Mod2: another main
```

I print `START` for a demo but the file does not have to be opened from `main`.

Please develop the printer module further as suitable. For example, add a way for the file name to be passed optionally so that `main` can name the log (by varying type and number of arguments), and add a way to close the log controllably.