# What type is STDOUT, and how do I optionally write to it?

Tags: perl, stdout, filehandle

Does STDOUT have a "type"?

```
printf STDERR ("STDOUT = %s\n", STDOUT);
printf STDERR ("\*STDOUT = %s\n", *STDOUT);
printf STDERR ("\\\*STDOUT = %s\n", \*STDOUT);
```

Produces:

```
STDOUT = STDOUT
*STDOUT = *main::STDOUT
\*STDOUT = GLOB(0x600078848)
```

I understand the `*main::STDOUT` and `GLOB(0x600078848)` entries.  The "bareword" one leaves me curious.

I'm asking because I want to pass a file handle-like argument to a method call.  In 'C', I'd use a file descriptor or a File *.  I want it to default to STDOUT.  What I've done is:

```
$OUT_FILE_HANDLE = \*STDOUT;
if(@ARGV > 0 ) {
    open($OUT_FILE_HANDLE, ">", "$ARGV[0]") or die $!;
}
```

It works, but I don't know exactly what I've done.  Have I botched up STDOUT?  I suspect I have "ruined" (overwritten) STDOUT, which is NOT what I want.

Please pardon the compound question;  they seemed related.

Comment: The `STDOUT` in `printf STDERR ("STDOUT = %s\n", STDOUT);` is an example of the "poetry optimization" compatibility misfeature -- the `STDOUT` bareword is treated as a literal string, the same as `"STDOUT"`. That's an error with `use strict`, which you should **always** use. As to your claim of understanding typeglobs and handles -- great for you! I always have to think of how they're implemented in the interpreter in order to make sense of the mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#The-Syntax-of-Variable-Names):

> Perl identifiers that begin with digits or punctuation characters are exempt from the effects of the `package` declaration and are always forced to be in package `main`; they are also exempt from `strict 'vars'` errors. A few other names are also exempt in these ways: [...] `STDOUT`

So, `STDOUT` is a global variable containing a pre-opened file handle.

From [perlfunc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#open-FILEHANDLE%2cEXPR):

> If FILEHANDLE is an undefined scalar variable (or array or hash element), a new filehandle is autovivified, meaning that the variable is assigned a reference to a newly allocated anonymous filehandle. Otherwise if FILEHANDLE is an expression, its value is the real filehandle.

Your `$OUT_FILE_HANDLE` is not undefined, so it is its value, `STDOUT`, that is being opened. AFAIK, if you open an already open handle, it is implicitly closed first.

There are several ways to do what you want. The first is obvious from the above quote — do not define `$OUT_FILE_HANDLE` before the `open`:

```
if (@ARGV > 0 ) {
  open($OUT_FILE_HANDLE, ">", "$ARGV[0]") or die $!;
} else {
  $OUT_FILE_HANDLE = \*STDOUT;
}
# do stuff to $OUT_FILE_HANDLE
```

Another is to use `select`, so you don't need to pass a file handle:

```
if (@ARGV > 0 ) {
  open($OUT_FILE_HANDLE, ">", "$ARGV[0]") or die $!;
  select $OUT_FILE_HANDLE;
}
# do stuff (without specifying a file handle)
select STDOUT;
```

Comment: `select` is probably the more perl/lisp thing to do.  I was also thinking of a dynamically scoped `STDOUT`.  This may be how select is implemented.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Create a lexical filehandle to be a copy of `STDOUT` and manipulate that as needed

```
sub manip_fh { 
    my ($fh) = @_;
    say $fh "hi STDOUT";                       # goes to STDOUT
    open my $fh, '>', 'a_file.txt' or die $!;  # now it's to a file
    say $fh "hello file";
}

open my $fh, '>&', STDOUT;  # via dup(2)

manip_fh($fh);

say "hi";  # still goes where STDOUT went before being dup-ed (terminal)
```

This new, independent, filehandle can then be reopened to another resource without affecting `STDOUT`.  See [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

The `$OUT_FILE_HANDLE = \*STDOUT;` from the question creates an alias and so the `STDOUT` does indeed get changed when the "new" one changes. You can see that by printing the [typeglob](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles)

```
our $NEW = \*STDOUT;  # "our" only for checks here, otherwise better "my"
say *{$main::NEW};    #--> *main::STDOUT
```

or by printing the `IO` slot from the symbol table for both

```
say for *{$main::NEW}{IO}, *{$main::{STDOUT}}{IO};
```

and seeing (that the object stringifies to) the same (eg `IO::File=IO(0x1a8ca50)`).

When it's duped using `open` with mode `>&` as in the first code snippet -- and as a global `our` instead of `my`, for these checks to be possible -- it prints `*main::NEW`, and its `IO::File` object is not the same as for `STDOUT`.

Make it a global `our` *only* so that it is in the symbol table for these checks (local lexicals declared with `my` aren't), but not otherwise; it is much *much* better having a `my`.

Answer (score 2):

This part of your question wasn't answered:

> *The "bareword" one leaves me curious.*

An identifier with no other meaning is a string literal that produces itself.<sup>[1]</sup> For example, `foo` is the same as `'foo'`.

```
$ perl -e'my $x = foo; print "$x\n";'
foo
```

This is error-prone, so we use `use strict qw( subs );` to prevent this.

```
$ perl -e'use strict; my $x = foo; print "$x\n";'
Bareword "foo" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

---

1. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58263206/589924) for other meanings Perl could assign.

Comment: I thought it sometime was interpreted as a `sub`?  I don't know, since I always `use strict`.  I had to take it out for this example, just to see what would happen.

Comment: It's interpreted as a sub call if a sub with that name has previously been declared. That's one of the "other meanings" to which I referred.

Comment: I've got another question, but I don't know how to phrase it.  Is there a programmatic way to see/know  how the compiler is going to interpret a bare word?  In my program above, I tried to print STDOUT, and it hit #8, and not #7.  I think.

Comment: You can use `-MO=Concise` or `-MO=Concise,-exec` to see how the program is compiled. /// That list is original content created for this answer. There could be a mistake, but I'm pretty confident due to extensive testing. (If anyone thinks there's a situation in which they think Perl interprets an identifier differently than this chart, I would very much like to hear about it so I can fix the chart). /// If you're referring to `printf STDERR ("STDOUT = %s\n", STDOUT);`, `printf`: #5, `STDERR`: #7, `STDOUT`: #8

Comment: The two examples of **4** are completely different, and only one of them will override **5**. Compare `perl -le 'use constant length => 7; print length'` (fails to override `length`) with `perl -le 'BEGIN { package P; *{main::length} = sub(){ 17 } } print length'` (handcrafted Exporter, overrides `length`, constant folding just like `use constant`).

Comment: @mosvy, Thanks. Moved `use constant` from #4 to #6