# How to open a filehandle with an existing variable in perl?

Tags: perl, filehandle

In my Perl script, I would like to process lines from either `STDIN` or a given file, if specified, as common with Linux/UNIX command line utilities.

To this end, I have the following section in my script (simplified for the post):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in = \*STDIN;
open $in, '<', $ARGV[0] or die if (defined $ARGV[0]);
print while (<$in>);
```

Essentially, I define `$in` to be a reference to the `STDIN` typeglob, so normally, if no argument is specified, the script does `print` for each line of `<STDIN>`. So far, so good.

If `$ARGV[0]` is defined however, I would like to read lines from that. That is what the second meaningful line purports to do. However, it seems that no lines are processed when ran with an argument.

---

I noticed that after my conditional call to `open`, `$in` does not change, even when I expect it to;

```
my $in = \*STDIN;
print $in, "\n";

open $in, '<', $ARGV[0] or die if (defined $ARGV[0]);
print $in, "\n";
```

yields

```
GLOB(0xaa08b2f4f28)
GLOB(0xaa08b2f4f28)
```

even when `$ARGV[0]` is defined. Does `open` not work when the first variable passed is already referring to a filehandle?

The relevant documentation does include the following

> About filehandles
>
> The first argument to open, labeled FILEHANDLE in this reference, is usually a scalar variable. (Exceptions exist, described in "Other considerations", below.) If the call to open succeeds, then the expression provided as FILEHANDLE will get assigned an open filehandle. That filehandle provides an internal reference to the specified external file, conveniently stored in a Perl variable, and ready for I/O operations such as reading and writing.

Based on this alone, I do not see why my code would not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's precisely what the [null filehandle <>](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) does

> Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line.

So all you need is

```
while (<>) { 
    ...
}
```

(see the rest of what docs say about it)

Another, in some cases safer option, is to use a double diamond bracket

```
while (<<>>) { }
```

> Using double angle brackets inside of a while causes the open to use the three argument form (with the second argument being `<`), so all arguments in `ARGV` are treated as literal filenames (including "-"). (Note that for convenience, if you use `<<>>` and if `@ARGV` is empty, it will still read from the standard input.)

(again, please see the rest of what docs say)

---

For the second part of the question, and following a discussion in comments, it is worth noting that `my $in = \*STDIN` creates *an alias* to `STDIN` (not a copy); see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57156978/4653379). Then [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#open)-ing a file with such scalar (that had previously been assigned a reference to a typeglob) as filehandle merely redirects the original typeglob. So here once we `open` the `$in` filehandle then `STDIN` winds up connected to that file.

This is easily checked

```
perl -wE'
    $in = \*STDIN; 
    say "\$in: $$in";                   #--> *main::STDIN
    print while <$in>;                  # type input, then Ctrl-D
    open $in, "<", $ARGV[0] or die $!; 
    say "\$in is: $$in";                #--> *main::STDIN
    print while <$in>;                  # but prints the file
    seek $in, 0, 0; 
    print while <STDIN>;                # prints the file
' file
```

After we type in some input, which is printed back, and Ctrl-D, after `open`-ing the file the filehandle is shown to still be `STDIN` but it does print out that file.  Then printing `STDIN` still prints the file.

The `STDIN` has been reconnected by `open` to the file; getting it back isn't simple. So if one is to actually associate `STDIN` with a lexical then better [dupe](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Duping-filehandles) it. See docs and the linked post.

---

As for the direct question -- yes, one can reassign a filehandle by `open`-ing it.

But the `... or die if ...` syntax is wrong as one cannot chain conditionals like that.

However, I cannot reproduce the shown behavior as your code actually works for me (on 5.16 and 5.30 on Linux).  My best guess then is that such code results in an "undefined behavior" and we get unpredictable and inconsistent behaviors.

Consider

```
E1 or E2 if E3;
```

where `E`s stand for Expressions.  (This is for `open(...) or die($!) if COND;`)

What should `if E3` apply to -- the lone `E2` or the whole `E1 or E2`? There is no way to tell and what one may well get then is the dreaded "undefined behavior" (UB) -- it may actually work, sometimes/under some conditions/on some systems, or *anything* else may happen.

Now, there may be a little more to it: `E2 if E3` *cannot* be a part of a condition so the interpretation of it all as `E1 or (E2 if E3);` is directly illegal syntax so perhaps in my program the statement is interpreted as

```
(E1 or E2) if E3;
```

which is fine (and works as intended, as it happens).  However, the original statement still must be UB and on OP's system it doesn't work.

Thus if you do need to have a filehandle *at a minimum* can fix that by adding parenthesis

```
(open $in, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!) if defined $ARGV[0];
```

But I'd recommend writing a nice and readable test instead of cramming it into one statement (and dup-ing `STDIN` to start with).

Comment: Ah. I knew about `<>` but I thought it is basically `<STDIN>` and that’s it. Thank you. Could you also please shed some light on why my overcomplicated solution failed?

Comment: @bp99 A filehandle can be reassigned just as you want -- but that `... or die if ...` isn't right as one can't chain conditionals like that.  (Remove it to test.)  I'm trying to figure out what (exactly) is wrong with it and why you get what you show.

Comment: @bp99 I can't reproduce the behavior you show (it just works for me, on 5.16 and 5.30 ??), but `... or die if ...` is not right -- instead, you'd want to test nicely.  And you can reassign a filehandle just as you want.  (While `while (<<>>) {}` does what you want.)

Comment: @bp99 My best guess at the moment is that `... or die if  ...` results in "undefined behavior"

Comment: @bp99  Amended the answer...

Comment: I also suspected that the `or die if` construct may be the culprit, but even when simply doing `my $in = \*STDIN; print $in; open $in, '<', $ARGV[0]; print $in;` the same thing is printed twice (when ran as `perl script test.txt`)

Comment: @bp99  That `print $in` prints the variable, not from a filehandle (`print <$fh>`) -- a typo?

Comment: @bp99 As for syntax, consider `E1 or E2 if E3;` (where `E`s are expressions) -- what should `if E3` apply to? Is it `E2` alone (`E2 if E3`) or all of `E1 or E2` (like `(E1 or E2) if E3;`) ...?  There is no way for the interpreter to tell.  So it's not right, no question -- while it may do as expected, as well -- this is why I expect UB.

Comment: Not a typo. I thought that when printing the _variable_ with `print`, I would see that it has a different identifier after the ‘reassignment’ via `open`. I think I am also correct, consider `my $in = \*STDIN; print $in; $in = \*STDOUT; print $in;` which outputs `GLOB(0xde31e76af28)GLOB(0xde31e76af58)` for me; clearly, the value changes. But when I execute the code in my previous comment, I get `GLOB(0x6510eca1f28)GLOB(0x6510eca1f28)`, as if `$in` did not even change. (Forgive me for assigning `\*STDOUT` to a variable called `in`)

Comment: It would be clearer to `print $$in` instead of `print $in`. Then I see `*main::STDIN` printed twice in the problematic case. Even though I just did an `open` to a file.

Comment: For the record, I see and agree with your point about the conditional statement. But my issue persists regardless of the conditional.

Comment: @bp99 OK, good points.  As for `print $in` I would guess that it uses the same memory location (for the second assignment).  But, then why do I get `STDIN` twice...

Comment: @bp99 Very interesting -- I do get `STDIN` after opening a file to `$in` as well -- but when I then print from the actual filehandle right after, `print $$in; print <$fh>`, it does print the file!

Comment: @bp99 Ah, right -- it _is_ still `STDIN` but it is set (connected) to that file.  Still, why -- I guess `STDIN` is special so once we open a filehandle to it then that's that? Reassigning the filehandle then just reconnects `STDIN` to a different resource?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244617/discussion-between-bp99-and-zdim).

Comment: @bp99  Updated the post, following up on our discussion

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the magical `ARGV` file handle, which does exactly what you want.

The following is the the safest way to read from it:

```perl
while (<<>>) {
   ...
}
```

---

You were going for something like this:

```perl
my $in_fh;
if ( @ARGV ) {
  open( $in_fh, "<", $ARGV[0] )
     or die( "Can't open `$ARGV[0]`: $!\n" );
} else {
   $in_fh = \*STDIN;
}

while (<$in_fh>) {
   ...
}
```

However, unlike unix tools, this only reads from the first file provided. Using the first solution reads from each file provided.

Comment: Minor nitpick: I think `while (<$fh_in>)` should be `while (<$in_fh>)`.